# Weird Dog statue in Donnie Darko

Tags: donnie-darko, set-design

I was rewatching Donnie Darko recently. At the high school Donnie attends there is this weird dog statue there. [Youtube Clip of dog statue](https://youtu.be/qsyfGwlf_l0?t=65). Super creepy looking and strange stance on it.

I was wondering if it was a real statue. I was thinking maybe the high school it was filmed at had that statue there. But from my cursory Google searches the movie was filmed at Loyola High School, on Venice Boulevard in Los Angeles. I didn't see a statue in any searches for that high school.

Anyway I was wondering if there was a story behind that statue. It just looks so weird. I guess maybe they wanted it to look weird since the movie is weird. I'm just mostly looking for any information about the dog statue and why it exists.

Comment: Looks like a statue of a school mascot to me, as such I strongly suspect it would have been put in place for filming and then removed later.  I couldn't find any corroborating evidence that the in-movie school's mascot is a bulldog, though.

Comment: I'm not sure any school would want something **that** ugly for a mascot, but that's just me.

Comment: The IRL school's mascot is a [cub](https://www.loyolahs.edu/studentlife/cub-corner/), so I suspect that it was set dressing for the movie only.

Comment: Is that not the statue that ends up with an axe embedded in it's head? That alone would suggest it was a prop just for the movie.

Comment: it seems to me that is a representation of the school mascot, taking into account the weird rabbit that appears constantly looks really related.